# Google Earth Engine reduce region

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers, reduceregion

I don't understand `ee.Image.reduceRegion()`. If I specify the region as a table containing multiple features, does it use the geometry of the first feature or all the features? The doc says the geometry is "The region over which to reduce data. Defaults to the footprint of the image's first band." But since I am reducing over a table and not image, I don't think this helps.

I have a shapefile containing multiple features. I created a dissolved version of it that has only one feature in QGIS. Then I uploaded both the original shapefile and the dissolved shapefile. I tried using `ee.Image.reduceRegion()` twice, one time using the original shapefile as geometry, and the other time using the dissovled shapefile as geometry. My reducer was linearRegression. The results were different. So I assume `ee.Image.reduceRegion()` takes only the first feature of the `geometry` parameter if it is a Table. But it wasn't specifically mentioned in the doc so I am not sure.

So just to restate the question: Does `ee.Image.reduceRegion()` reduce over all the (dissovled-like) features or just the first one when the geometry is a table containing multiple features?

Note I am not asking whether it gets a stat for each feature's geometry (I assume that is `ee.Image.reduceRegions()`), but rather does it get a stat for all of the features' geometries combined or just one of the feature's geometry.

Answer (score 1):

`reduceRegion()` expects a geometry, not a collection. *Whenever* you pass a collection where a geometry is expected, all of the collection's features' geometries are retrieved and **unioned**.

So, all of the area covered by any of the collection's features will be included in the reduction (and *not* double-counted in the case of overlap).

This union can be an expensive operation with large collections or complex geometry, and it is good practice to avoid it if you don't need it. So for example, if you are reducing with `ee.Reducer.sum()` and your feature collection is large, it would be best to use `reduceRegions()` and sum the results, rather than to use `reduceRegion()` on a collection.

Comment: In that case why was the result for the dissolved and original shapefile different? The goemetry of dissolved and union features should be the same, right? I suppose it could be because the dissolved shapefile was too big, and GEE had to break it to more than one feature, and maybe something happened there. I would have to check.

Comment: Also, could you please provide the doc reference to "Whenever you pass a collection where a geometry is expected, all of the collection's features' geometries are retrieved and unioned". Thanks!

Comment: @Sara Unfortunately, I don't know of a single page explaining the issue at this time. [`ee.FeatureCollection.geometry`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-geometry?hl=en) does document the behavior and performance consideration, but I don't know if it's documented that that is the same operation used whenever a collection considered as a feature is asked for its geometry.